# Convert two Pandas Dataframes into a dictionary of tuples for each group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I currently have two DataFrames, named "means" and "variances", each grouped by 'Class' feature, as shown.

means DataFrame:

```
         Pregnancies     Glucose     BP
Class                
0        4.00            99.8        56.0
1        4.75            130         62.5
```

variances DataFrame:

```
         Pregnancies     Glucose     BP
Class                
0        9.10            698         326
1        14.1            1023        463
```

I would like to return a dictionary of two key-value pairs, with the keys equal to the class numbers, and the values as tuples containing the mean and variance values for each feature in the dataframes, as shown here:

```
dict = {0:[(4.00, 9.10), (99.8, 698), (56.0, 326)],
        1:[(4.75, 14.1), (130, 1023), (62.6, 463)]}
```

Still working on my data manipulation skills. For reference, this is part of building a Naive Bayes classifier from (close to) scratch. The theory of Naive Bayes classification is not difficult for me to understand, the part I'm obviously struggling with is formatting my data correctly.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to concatenate your dataframes, then use `groupby` + `apply`:

```
res = pd.concat([means, variances])\
        .groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: list(map(tuple, x.values.T))).to_dict()

print(res)

{0: [(4.0, 9.1), (99.8, 698.0), (56.0, 326.0)],
 1: [(4.75, 14.1), (130.0, 1023.0), (62.5, 463.0)]}
```

If a list of lists is sufficient, more readable would be `lambda x: x.values.T.tolist()`.